# Nested document update MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5925e2213daf48359cb5429e"), 
    "email" : "test3@gmail.com", 
    "firstname" : "test3", 
    "friends" : [
        {
            "friend_email" : "test2@gmail.com", 
            "status" : 1, 
            "fname" : "test2"
        },
        {
            "friend_email" : "test1@gmail.com", 
            "status" : 1, 
            "fname" : "test1"
        }
    ]
}
```

My database looks like above. 
The "friends" can have many entries inside it. I have to search a particular entry (depending upon a variable value) with (suppose) friend_email = "test2@gmail.com" and email = "test3@gmail.com" and change its particular field "status" to 0.
I have written this following update query,

```
collection_temp.update({

        "email": email(test3@gmail.com) ,     
        "friends" :
         {$elemMatch : 
                 {"friend_email" : friend_req_sent_to (test2@gmail.com)}
         }},
         {"$set":
                {"friends.$.status" : 0}
    },

    function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");

        } else {
            console.log("FAIL");
        }
    });
```

My query runs correctly but the status field does not change....please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you try to run the query separately and then call the respective functions?? maybe easy that way??

Comment: Strange I did a quick test of your query and it worked fine. How are you verifying that the value of the property "status" hasn't changed? Do you mind double checking your collection name, one described in the code against what is in the db.

Comment: @JayNirgudkar Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 1):

The query works fine, you may be returning incorrect values from those functions you are using (`email` and `friend_req_sent_to`).

With all `status` fields set to 1, running:

```
db.test.update({
    email: "test3@gmail.com",
    friends: { $elemMatch: { friend_email: "test2@gmail.com" } }
}, { $set: { "friends.$.status": 0 } })
```

Returns:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

And if I check with a `find` I can see the document was properly updated.